# How to open binary image data in Windows Photo Viewer in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, imagesource

I'd like to open an image file stored in the database in Windows Photo Viewer through my c# code. I know how to open an image file when the image file path is known

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\image.png")

but I don't want to save the image locally. Is there a way to display the image in Windows Photo Viewer if I have ImageSource?

> ImageSource image = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(imageByteArray) as ImageSource;

Comment: Why do you want to use Photo Viewer? Just display the image on your own in your application. I don't think that Windows Photo Viewer accepts anything else than files.

Comment: I will if I have to but I'd rather display images in the Photo Viewer because I can copy, save, print, email, open the image in other applications from the Photo Viewer. I don't want to code all those things in my applications.

Comment: “I can copy, save, print, email, open the image in other applications from the Photo Viewer” these things are all based on a file, a real file.u can't do these things based on ImageSource.If you want do these operations in your application,or drap/drop pic from your application to desktop/e-mail and so on , you must convert  ImageSource to a local file firstly.

Comment: Short answer, its not possible without saving your image to a file. Get a temp location if you don't want to clutter the users folders and don't forget to delete the temp file when you're done.